# How do you link to site-wide static files in django 1.8?

Tags: css, django, static

Current structure:

```
MySite
  |--MySite
  |    |--static
  |         |--MySite
  |              |-- site_wide.css
  |--MyApp
       |--static
            |--MyApp
                 |-- app_specific.js
                 |-- app_specific.css
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/MySite/static/"),
)
```

With the following code I am able to successfully link to `app_specific.js` and `app_specific.css`, but am unable to link `site_wide.css`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'MyApp/app_specific.css %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'MySite/site_wide.css' %}" />

... site body ...

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'MyApp/app_specific.js' %}" ></script>
```

Upon inspecting the generated html, the href for the 2nd link is:

```
href="/static/MySite/site_wide.css"
```

which does not exist.

My current understanding is that django would search for my linked file in the path defined by `STATIC_URL` and then (if not found) progress through the paths listed in `SATICFILES_DIRS`, however it is apparently never looking at the path specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

I am brand new to django and want to understand how it works. Some other similar questions mention things like `collectstaticfiles` or something like that but are all very unclear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Everything I know is from the official Django 1.8 tutorial/docs, so please do not post deprecated answers. 1.8 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/MySite/static/')` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'MySite/static')`, i. e. remove forwarding `/`. I guess the reason is how `os.path.join` works

```
>>> os.path.join('/foo', '/bar')
'/bar'
>>> os.path.join('/foo', 'bar')
'/foo/bar'
```