# Configuring PythonAnywhere for django 1.8 static files

Tags: django, static, pythonanywhere

In PythonAnywhere Web tab:

```
URL:     /static/
Path:    /home/username/project/static
```

In settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

...

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static'),
)
```

In template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link type="text/css" href="{% static 'MyApp/style.css' %}" />
<link type="text/css" href="{% static 'project/style.css' %}" />
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'MyApp/script.js' %}" ></script>
```

I run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

which successfuly copies all static files into `/home/username/project/static`, however I get 404 errors for all static files. I am only having this error on PythonAnywhere. Everything runs fine on localhost.

The generated html and the 404 errors indicate the files are being searched for at the following locations:

```
http://username.pythonanywhere.com/static/MyApp/style.css
http://username.pythonanywhere.com/static/project/style.css
http://username.pythonanywhere.com/static/MyApp/script.js
```

This is what I expected, so I am assuming my misunderstanding lies in where these directories actually lie in PythonAnywhere.

I am very new to Django. See my question: [How do you link to site-wide static files in django 1.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676929/how-do-you-link-to-site-wide-static-files-in-django-1-8) for a more detailed description of my static files structure.

P.S. I am using Django 1.8 in a virtualenv on PA, so please no deprecated/out of date answers.

UPDATE:

project structure:

```
project/
    project/
        static/            //STATICFILES_DIRS
            project/
                style.css  //site-wide style sheet
    MyApp/
        static/            //auto-search by {% static %} tag in local dev
            MyApp/
                style.css  //app-specific stylesheet
                script.js  //app-specific js
    static/                //STATIC_ROOT for production   
        project/           //copied by collectstatic
            ...            //same as above
        MyApp/             //same as above
            ...            //same as above
```

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassing... Forgot to reload PA.

For future reference, this *is* how you configure PA and django 1.8 static files according to the 1.8 documentation.

Don't forget to reload!

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` should not point to the same path. `STATIC_ROOT` is where files are copied to be served for your **production** environment, usually by Apache or Nginx.

`STATICFILES_DIRS` are served by the static application during **local** development.

I typically structure my projects as such:

```
my_project/
    my_project/
    static_assets/  <- STATICFILES_DIRS
        images/
        css/
        less/
        js/
    static/         <- STATIC_ROOT
    templates/
```

A link to a css file, for example would look like:

```
{% static 'css/foo.css' %}
```

the top level directory specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS` is ommitted. From the looks of your sample code, it looks like your `{% static %}` paths are not pointing to the right location.

See the [static files app docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) for more information.

Comment: My `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` do not point to the same path. I will edit question to show project structure

Comment: and as I said, the `{% static %}` tags are working properly in local development

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect that static directory structure to work, or what you're trying to accomplish. You really need **single** entry point for static files to be served on.

Comment: The django 1.8 documentation repeatedly emphasizes that namespacing your apps static files is good practice, hence the `project/MyApp/static/MyApp` paths for local development. Running `collectstatic` puts all my files into `project/static/` (my `STATIC_ROOT`, just like in your structure). Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: It's largely a matter of opinion. I typically don't namespace my static files per application module. I tend to take a more componentized approach, which means that a CSS or JS file is going to span more than one application. Trying to split up CSS by app module would lead to some very fragmented code, in my opinion.

Comment: The reasoning is to keep apps modular and portable. I can move my entire app directory and bring all the relevant CSS with it. Off-topic though. Looking at my `STATIC_ROOT` and PA configuration, can you see any reason they would 404?

Comment: If I'm writing something re-usable, I will structure my app module in a manner that is similar to yours. From what I can tell, your uppermost "MyApp" directory also needs to go under your `STATICFILES_DIRS` directory, or get added to that tuple.

Comment: `MyApp/` is auto-included in the static search paths (which is for local only anyway). After `collectstatic` all needed files are found in `static/` on the filesystem, but 404 when searching for `http://username.pythonanywhere.com/static/...`. That's my question.

Comment: What makes you think `MyApp` is automatically included in the static search paths?

Comment: In local development, `STATIC_URL = "/static/"` and `STATICFILES_DIRS = ()` (the default settings) result in `{% static %}` linking successfully to `MyApp/static/`. Likewise, `collectstatic` copies from there without being included in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. It is explained in the django 1.8 docs

Comment: OK, I see in the 1.8 docs where `static` directories contained in app modules listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` are automatically traversed (I usually don't take this approach), so the problem seems to be on the Python Anywhere side, in my opinion, but I couldn't tell you what it is. Have you opened a trouble ticket with them?

Comment: Hah. My bad. Forgot to reload PA. Edit your answer telling me to reload and i'll mark correct. Thanks for making me hyper-analyze my structuring. It actually helped me learn quite a bit.

Comment: No, that's ok. I didn't really answer your question. You should answer your own question. That would be more appropriate.

Comment: Will do. Thank for the help anyway!